# Google-sheet IF function not working

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I need a formula in Google spreadsheet that will:

- +1 when the value is >=5,
- +2 when the value is >=10,
- +3 when the value is >=15,
- +4 when the value is >=20,
- +5 when the value is >=25

The formula I am currently using is:

```
=IF(F7>=5,H7+1,IF(F7>=10,H7+2,IF(F7>=15,H7+3,IF(F7>=20,H7+4,H7))))
```

This formula is working for the `+1` when the value is `>=5`, but when the value is `>=10,15,20,or 25` it is still only adding `+1`.

Please Help!

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 13 times.

Answer (score 0):

If the first condition is `F7>=5` then the result will always be `+1` wether `F7 = 5, 15,` or even `200`.
It's because the first condition `F7>=5` is always met.

Try this instead :

```
=IF(
   F7>=25,H7+5,
              IF(
               F7>=20,H7+4,
                           IF(
                            F7>=15,H7+3,
                                       IF(
                                          F7>=10,H7+2,
                                                      IF(F7>=5,H7+1,H7)
                                          )
                               )
                  )
       )
```

Comment: That worked and makes perfect sense! Thanks so much!

Comment: Don't forget to resolve the answer if this works, or ask another question. Have a nice day.